# How much time will it take to upgrade to Windows 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, upgrade

I'm planning to upgrade my Windows 7 PC to Windows 8.
I've read several articles concerning the upgrade. 
Now I ask myself how much time must be included to perfom the upgrade.

Does the upgrade take much longer than a new installation? (only the pure installation, without all backups and further configuration work)

Which steps Windows 8 will do additionally on an upgrade?

Comment: It depends very strongly on the hardware you're running on and the contents of the drive...there's no way to answer this well.  I had one system do it in under 10 minutes when testing with the RP.

Comment: Hi Martin! This question invites everyone to post their own answer, which is considered *not constructive*, sorry. These numbers will depend on a plethora of factors, so there's no single answer, as several others have already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it takes me around 30-45 minutes for a fresh install so I would assume at least 15 minutes more time as it has to migrate the old settings and files to Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the network connection you have now and the hardware you have.
For me, it takes 38 mins.
my computer:
Intel Dual-core 2.0GHz.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on various factors such as processor speed, hard drive write speed, the orientation of the moons of Jupiter etc.

But you can reasonably expect about 40-60 minutes on a mid-grade machine. Faster on SSD systems, slower on your Pentium 4.

Answer (score 0):

It depends both on how you are upgrading, and your hardware... if you are planing on doing an actual upgrade it will depend on how much data the installer has to move around. You could choose to back up your data, to a HD or Partition and do a clean install, which will drastically cut down on your upgrade, once again this will also depend on how much data you have, plus factor in installing all of your software.

For me it took about 15 mins to do a clean install, but I haven't restored my data or software yet, so that isn't really a fair guesstimate...

Answer (score 0):

I depends *a lot* on the hardware, but it took [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/10/the-windows-8-upgrade-install-experience/2/) 11 minutes for a fresh install and 27 for an upgrade install. This was on a fairly new computer that saw light daily use.